# change application name in openshift after myapp.war deployed

Tags: git, deployment, jboss, openshift

i have been trying to change my openshift cloud app name from

```
appname-domain.rhcloud.com to appname-domain.rhcloud.com/myapp/
```

as mentioned in this [link](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear) i have deployment my own custom war file in openshift jboss server.

but how to change my cloud url to this `appname-domain.rhcloud.com/myapp/`, where initially i deployed `ROOT.War` file, which now i want to deploy my war file as myapp.war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a WAR file you have to put the WAR file inside deployments directory of your OpenShift application. Rename the ROOT.war to myapp.war and copy it to deployments directory. Then run the following commands.

```
git add .
git commit -am "added myapp.war"
git push
```

Comment: i have followed your steps still no luck